# Wide characters and Unicode encoding

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

My **Perl** code prints some POST data to a log file.

Sometimes I experience the following error:

> Wide character in print at...

I realized that there is some problem with **encoding**.
So I added the following lines:

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
binmode STDERR, ':utf8';
```

However then the error changed to a different kind, with messages like this one:

> "\xFF" does not map to Unicode

So what is a proper way to make it work?

Comment: You are probably printing some non-utf8 data. Please check that the POST data is valid UTF8. See also [Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode)

Comment: Would you please show us the code that opens the log file handle?

Comment: @HåkonHægland - I don't know, because I cannot see what is coming. That is a reason why I am trying to print it to a log file. Is there a way how to safely print mixed data, `utf-8` and `non-uft-8` data?

Comment: @GMB - `open LOG, '>>', log_file;  binmode LOG, ':utf8';`

Comment: @Ωmega You can open the log file with mode `:raw`, the you can print any data to it :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland - `UTF-8 "\\xFF" does not map to Unicode at /usr/local/share/perl5/CGI.pm line 1116.`

Comment: Tip: `:std` causes `binmode` to be used in STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR with the provided layer, so no need to call `binmode` explicity

Answer (score 3):

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

does the following:

- Causes subsequent uses of `open` in the same scope to add `:encoding(UTF-8)` if no layers are passed to `open`.
- Causes the following to be executed:

  ```
  binmode(STDIN,  ':encoding(UTF-8)');
  binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
  binmode(STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
  ```

The problem is that the STDIN shouldn't be decoded.

**Solution #1**

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
BEGIN { binmode(STDIN); }
```

**Solution #2**

```
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';
BEGIN {
   binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
   binmode(STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
}
```